# tlmgr comes up with Japanese

Tags: tlmgr, japanese

I just started the tlmgr app on my iMac 11.1 and it comes up completely in Japanese. How can I change this?

My version:

```
tlmgr revision 57119 (2020-12-13 00:40:00 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/local/texlive/2020
TeX Live (https://tug.org/texlive) version 2020
```

Comment: Do other apps also come in Japanese? What's the main language *supposed* to be?

Comment: German DE, and no other problems

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue: I had German as first language and Japaner as second. It seems, that the app is ignoring the German setting but using the second language. If I have English as second language, everything is working fine. If I change the second language to Italian and have Japanese after this language, then I get Japanese again. So one has to add English at least as second language.

Comment: Maybe the application only has an English and a Japanese localization, but not a German one.